# How to transform and create a pandas column with 0 and 1 based on specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, churn

I want to create a column `churn` as shown.
The code should group and compare each year's column `Col` and assign 0 if it finds `Col` value in next year.

In this example 3rd row is missing from 2017. Hence assigning 1.

How do I do this in pandas?

```
State ID    Col   Year  cost  Churn
CT    123   M     2016  10    0
CT    123   C     2016  15    0
CT    123   A     2016  10    1
CT    123   C     2016  20    0
CT    123   M     2017  10    0
CT    123   C     2017  15    0
```

Comment: what if a customer leaves and then returns? i.e. A appears in 2015, is missing from 2016, and then appears again in 2017?

Comment: If A disappear in 2016, then assign 1 in year 2015 because they churned. If they come back in 2017, then assign 0 because thats a new customer they have not churned

Answer (score 2):

First add all missing combinations of first 4 columns by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html), then shift per first 3 columns by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and last use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for original order and remove all added rows (if no parameter `on` it use all columns wich are same in both DataFrames):

```
s = df.assign(Churn=0).set_index(['State','ID','Col','Year'])['Churn']
df1 = df.merge(s.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels), fill_value=1)
                .groupby(level=[0,1,2])
                .shift(-1, fill_value=0)
                .reset_index())
print (df1)
  State   ID Col  Year  Churn
0    CT  123   M  2016      0
1    CT  123   C  2016      0
2    CT  123   A  2016      1
3    CT  123   M  2017      0
4    CT  123   C  2017      0
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without index, I get error on saying `cannot handle a non-unique multi-index`, also don't understand why are shifting -1. I am trying to compare a combination of columns and column `Col` within each year to decide churn

Comment: @Priyank - It means there are duplicates, like first `C` in sample data is `M`, how are processing this data?

Comment: I understand there are duplicates but not sure why that is important in calculating `churn` indicator. If a combination repeats within a year it's fine, if it repeats in next year then 0 if it doesn't then 1 in the previous year

Comment: @Priyank - yop, agree. There are columns only `['State','ID','Col','Year']` in input data? If yes, then change `s = df.assign(Churn=0).set_index(['State','ID','Col','Year'])['Churn']` to `s = df.drop_duplicates().assign(Churn=0).set_index(['State','ID','Col','Year'])['Churn']`

Comment: Actually, there are other column in the data which are relevant and have different values for in same year. I tried `drop_duplicates` gives me same error

Comment: @Priyank - ok, then use `s = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['State','ID','Col','Year']).assign(Churn=0).set_index(['State','ID','Col','Year'])['Churn']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219585/discussion-between-priyank-and-jezrael).